# .NET Framework-4.0-version-user is having a trouble installing the OpenTelemetry Agent

Tags: .net-framework-version, datadog, open-telemetry, apm

I'm asking this question on behalf of my customer.

They're using <.NET Framework version 4.0> so considering installing the OpenTelemetry agent to use Datadog's APM, which technically supports only the higher version (version 4.6.1).

According to the [documentation on netframework](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/net/netframework/) I referenced, OpenTelemetry supports both .NET and .NET Framework, which is an older Windows-based implementation of .NET.

However, when attempting to install the required NuGet packages (OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNet and OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting), they encountered an issue. Both packages require .NET Framework 4.6 or higher, while they're using .NET Framework 4.0. They even tried installing the earliest (beta) version of the packages, but it also required at least .NET Framework version 4.5.

They don't know any other way to install the OpenTelemetry agent apart from using the NuGet packages that are currently available. Could anyone please help me with the guidance of installing the OpenTelemetry agent that supports the lower version?

Thank you!

Comment: Support for 4.0 ended more than 7 years ago. I don't think you'll find any solution that doesn't require a lot of engineering work.

Comment: The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. You *have* to upgrade to 4.6.2, if only to be able to connect to any API that uses HTTPS and requires TLS1.2 without dirty hacks. I'm surprised the customer's code worked at all given that almost every single service requires TLS 1.2 since 2016. All cloud services require it, it's a PCI-DSS requirement since 2020.

Comment: Is the customer sure they're using .NET Framework 4.0? All supported *Windows* versions come with 4.6.x installed, so the customer almost certainly uses a newer version. Windows 8.1 came with 4.5.1. The .NET 4.x runtimes were binary replacements which means that installing a newer version replaces the older ones but you can't install an older version over a newer one. Unless the customer uses Windows XP (End Of Life 2014), they're probably running or 4.5 if not newer. It's quite likely the runtime was updated to a newer version through Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

Both https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTelemetry/1.4.0 and https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/releases/tag/v0.7.0 supports only .NET Framework 4.6.2+ and .NET  6+.

There is no possibility to use it with older (unsupported) versions.
As a reference please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework and https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet (out of support section).